# getting the pid of a subshell command

Tags: bash, shell, init, pid, subshell

I am trying to write a init service script for a java program. I have the following in the init script.

```
$USER = awesomeuser

$PROGRAM_CMD = "java -server com.test.TestClass"

$PROGRAM_LOG = "/var/log/awesome_log"

sudo -u $USER nohup $PROGRAM_CMD >> $PROGRAM_LOG 2>&1 </dev/null &
server_pid=$!
echo $server_pid > $pidfile
```

What is happening is I am getting the pid of the parent process but I really want the the pid of the java process running from within the subshell.

Is there anyway I can structure the command so I get the subshell command pid back?

Thanks!

Comment: `$USER = awesomeuser` -- is this really `bash`? Looks like PHP.

Comment: You need to learn basic `bash` syntax. Variable assignments are like `USER=awesomuser` -- No `$` before the variable, and no spaces around the `=`.

Comment: That is *not* subshell. That's a [sub process which happens to be a shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/261638/is-a-sub-shell-the-same-thing-as-a-child-shell).

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
sudo -u $USER nohup $PROGRAM_CMD >> $PROGRAM_LOG 2>&1 </dev/null &
```

try this:

```
sudo -u $USER bash -c "nohup $PROGRAM_CMD >> $PROGRAM_LOG 2>&1 & </dev/null; echo "'$!'
```

`sudo` usually spawns child process and calls `exec` in it. `fork`-ing can be avoided with proper config of `sudo` (see `sudo(1)`). But it seems easier to me to set user and run another shell.

This approach seems better to me than obtaining pid of process by `ps | grep | blabla` as it avoids race condition: once shell has ran the background process, the only correct way to get pid is to print `$!` variable. Otherwise we can get pid of a wrong program, or even get no pid at all if `java` terminates quickly.

By the way, in order to assign proper values to your variables, the starting lines of your script should be

```
USER=awesomeuser
PROGRAM_CMD="java -server com.test.TestClass"
PROGRAM_LOG="/var/log/awesome_log"
```

instead of

```
$USER = awesomeuser
$PROGRAM_CMD = "java -server com.test.TestClass"
$PROGRAM_LOG = "/var/log/awesome_log"
```

Answer (score 1):

What's about using another script:

*findpid.sh*

```
#!/bin/bash
pid=""
pidfile="pid.log"

while [ -z "${pid}" ]; do
    pid=`ps -U "${1}" | grep "${2}" | xargs | cut -d" " -f 1`
done

echo "${pid}" > ${pidfile}
```

Then call findpid.sh in your script. You may use a timestamp when calling java in order to be sure you identify the right process with `ps`.

```
#!/bin/bash
USER=awesomeuser
TIME=`date +"%s"`
PROGRAM_CMD="java -server com.test.TestClass java -Dtime=${TIME}"
PROGRAM_LOG="awesome_log"

bash findpid.sh "${USER}" "${PROGRAM_CMD}" &
sudo -u $USER nohup $PROGRAM_CMD >> $PROGRAM_LOG 2>&1 </dev/null &
wait
```

Comment: Works good but there could be a race condition: process can be already dead at the moment of calling this sequence.

Comment: `ps | grep name` has a high chance of yielding the wrong processes.

Comment: @msw you are right. If the java is launched twice, incorrect pid my be retrieved. By including a timestamp in the java call, ps would have a better chance to identify the right process.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this without shell support and bash doesn't provide the primitives to do it right. Altering the interesting process to output or store its own PID is the right way.

If you can't alter the application code, you could use a cheezy wrapper like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

/*
 * pidder cmd args - launch cmd with args and print its pid
 */

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: pidder command [args]\n");
        exit(2);
    }

    switch(fork()) {
        case -1:
            perror("fork");
            exit(2);
        case 0:
            printf("%d\n", getpid());
            /* launch cmd with path search if relative path */
            execvp(argv[1], argv+1);
            perror("exec");
            exit(1);
        default:
            exit(0);
    }

}
```

If you use this, be aware that `$ ./pidder some_command` will have subtle differences from `$ some_command`, a simple example is that in the first case, the PPID will not be the invoking shell.

Comment: Have you checked out my answer below? Why do you think shell cannot be used to do it right?